# NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [Hustla/Location] in handler.php line 131

Tags: php, laravel-5, vuex

Trying to add in user messaging into my website. I have moved the messaging routes to the top of the web.php page, and tried a few other things, but it is just not quite working out. Anyone else have any ideas?

web.php

```
    Auth::routes();



//Messaging

Route::group(['prefix' => 'messaging', 'namespace' => 'Conversation'], function () {
        Route::get('/conversations', 'ConversationController@index')->name('conversation.index');
    });
```

conversationcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace Hustla\Http\Controllers\Conversation;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hustla\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ConversationController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Just not quite working out" is a very vague description of your problem. It would help if you explained what you've tried to do, what you expected to see and what you're actually seeing. It's also worth checking error logs.

If you're trying to view the route in a browser and nothing loads, then perhaps first check the list of compiled routes using `php artisan route:list` and check that there is an entry for it.

However, looking at your code, it might be a namespace issue you're having. In your route definition, setting the namespace attribute to "Conversation" will tell Laravel to look for the class `App\Http\Controllers\Conservation\ConversationController`, whereas your actual controller script is under the namespace `Hustla\Http\Controllers\Conversation`.

In the RouteServiceProvider class, you can specify the "root" namespace for your controller files.

```
/**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

You may want to update this value to "Hustla\Http\Controllers".